# Metropolitan Mollusks and Seagrass Serengetis

Tags: biology, environment, ecology

Knowledge has come to me recently that mussels can suck up pollutants, making them crucial cleanup crews in the New York filth.  This knowledge is the inspiration for this alternate scenario, in which coral, sponges and crinoids (flower-like relatives of the sea star) have been extinct for 65 million years.

[image]

To make the scenario even tighter, let us focus on the waters highlit in the map above, the oceans of the Tropics.  Temperate and polar waters undergo seasonal changes, which exclude them from this scenario.  Western South America and southwestern Africa are also excluded because they are chilled by coldwater currents, and cold currents carry nutrients, and a cloud of nutrients clouds up sunlight.

Reefs can be found only on the edges of continental shelves, where nutrients from the deep are pushed upwards to the surface.  The reefs here consist of clams, mussels, oysters, tunicates ("sea squirts"), goose barnacles, basket stars and worms belonging to Sabellidae (feather duster worms), Serpulidae (“Christmas tree” worms) and Siboglinidae (beard worms).  These reefbuilders can be found in greater numbers in the temperate and polar shallows worldwide.

Between the reefs and the tidal pools, one would expect bare, sandy seabed stretching the horizon.

[image]

But not here.  Instead, between the reefs and tidal pools are nothing but this:

[image]

Not seagrass meadows, as they are called back home, but seagrass **savannas**.  You can find both habitats put together worldwide in tropical shallows between Cancer and Capricorn (excluding western South America and Namibia, of course.)

A reef consisting primarily of mollusks have been known to suck up pollutants.  And seagrass, being plants, inhale carbon dioxide and exhale oxygen.  **Would a global union of both habitats (within the limits of 23.5 degrees latitude, of course) solve the bulk of the problems regarding ocean pollution and manmade greenhouse gases?**

Comment: I used to keep oysters but ocean acidification on top of radioactive fallout, I get marbles instead... I curse you everybody...

Comment: your big problem are places were the seafloor is hard, that's where corals thrive, often only building up sediment later as the create natural baffles. hard substrates will not support seagrass.  so something is going to evolve to take advantage of these open areas. then you have things like atolls.

Comment: @John  Hard and far away from any nutrients.  No, the reefs stay on the precipice.

Comment: Hard and swarming with nutrients, that's what filter feeding does pull nutrients directly from the water. naked rock is not good for sequestering carbon but coral is.

Comment: @John  The farther you are from currents, the harder it is to find food.  It's that simple.

Comment: There are already similar things, e.g. the kelp forests off the California coast, so one might expect that all environments that could be successfully colonized are already.  Also temperate & polar waters are generally more productive than tropical.

Comment: hard ground does not support seagrass, it does support coral which actually does something to achieve the stated goal of removing CO2 from the atmosphere, seagrass does not.  the more coral you replace with seagrass the LESS carbon you sequester.

Comment: @John  But as you can read, coral has been extinct for 65 million years.

Comment: @jamesqf  Yes, however, multitudes of nutrients dust down ocean quality, so the seagrass savannas stay in the tropics.

Comment: @ JDW I am trying to explain that not only does it not help solve the problem of greenhouse gasses it actually makes it worse is several ways. In addition it now has barren land where our world has thriving ecosystems.

Comment: @John  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JDW What doesn"t?

Comment: @John  "Barren land"?  Where did you get that?

Comment: If there is no coral, and seagrass does not live on hard substrates, and other filter feeders are somehow restricted to the continental shelf edges, then you have huge swaths of land with nothing on it. Reefs exist on many other places than just continental shelf edges. I even mentioned atolls.

Comment: Sp you get how replacing coral with seagrass does ot help greenhouse gas levels, how it actually makes it worse?

Comment: If real grass can grow on rock, then why not seagrass?  Reefs exist in proximity of currents, where there's food.

Comment: Also, the plants (or algae/cyanobacteria - let's just say anything that does photosynthesis) do not have to be anchored to the sea floor.  While I don't have actual numbers (feel free to do the search yourself), a simple look at the map would suggest that there's FAR more room in the deep ocean for free-floating photosynthesizers.  And indeed, everything from microscopic single-celled stuff to large seaweeds like sargasso does live there.

Comment: @JDW current =/= edges of the continental shelf. Coral also tends to pop up wherever there is sunlight, such as atolls. You are aware most corals house symbiotic photosynthetic algae right? Also real grass does not grow on rock, it can grow between rocks or on soil (which is mostly made or rock) whereas coral can grow on solid rock. Seagrass needs to pull nutrients from the soil, coral just needs anchorage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mollusc and worm reef builders will be fine for removing carbon dioxide from the atmosphere. Reef-building animals have been doing this for millions of years - including long before scleractinian corals evolved. It is the reason that the amount of carbon dioxide in Earth's atmosphere has declined over time. See [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45338/what-levels-of-atmospheric-carbon-dioxide-can-humans-cope-with-on-prehistoric-ea) I asked for some figures on CO2 in various geological periods.

They'll get in trouble if humans release enough CO2 to cause the oceans to become slightly more acidic. Calcium carbonate shells start to dissolve even in really weak acid, like vinegar. In such a case, the poor mollusc will be working flat out just to repair the acid erosion to its shell. The CO2 it is capturing will be used to replace the CO2 released by the shell surface dissolving, so there will be no net carbon capture.

I'm not sure how either molluscs or seagrasses would solve pollution problems such as plastic fragments.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking pollutants on the line of this:  http://www.natureworldnews.com/articles/8682/20140822/clams-mussels-clean-up-ocean-pollutants.htm   Also, won't seagrasses, being plants, do the job of CO2 removal?

Answer (score -1):

Plants don't reduce CO2, nor produce net oxygen. plants still have to respire as do the things that eat them. The carbon they take in is released during respiration either by them or whatever eats them. So seagrass fields will do nothing to affect CO2 concentrations unless you are periodically harvesting and burying them. Most forests are oxygen neutral as well and only sequester carbon at the rate of burial of fallen trees most of which get recycled and thus released. bogs are the areas that lock away carbon due to high burial and anoxic conditions. 
http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/CarbonCycle/carbon_cycle2001.pdf

I'll break it down, plants photosynthesis during daylight hours making oxygen and sugar out of CO2 and water, and respire all day and night turning sugar and oxygen back into CO2 and water. So the only carbon they lock away  (and the only net oxygen they produce) is in building their cellulose(sugar) tissue this gets rebalanced (oxy consumed CO2 released) as soon as they decay or are eaten. To get a net gain over the long run you need to sequester the carbon produced, the most common way is by burial, by locking it away in a anaerobic environment, which seagrass are not doing, or you can do what coral does and turn it into a mineral that is not getting digested.

Cyanobacteria are the things that produce huge quantities of net oxygen, becasue they mostly undergo anaerobic respiration to consume the sugars they produce, which does not consume oxygen. And when they die they tend to end up on the deep ocean floor which tends towards anoxic conditions.

Worse yet corals actually do sequester carbon, becasue the skeleton is made of calcium carbonate and it does not get recycled easily or often, unlike plant tissue. It is actually one of the most effective biological means of sequestering carbon. So you are actually slowing sequestration by not having corals. I should also mention that the symbiotic algae in coral does photosynthesize so if it was not for their skeletons they would be largely neutral as well.
http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/CarbonCycle/page2.php

Also reefs can be found in far more places than just the edges of continental shelves, atolls are a good example. Corals are not limited to the narrow locations you are limited your reefs to so you are trading carbon sequestration for either nothing or miniscule trace sequestration. This results in a net increase in atmospheric carbon across the globe.

Comment: Where did you get THAT?!

Comment: basic understanding of botany and the carbon cycle. but I will get you a source.

Comment: I still don't understand why you think the common knowledge of plants absorbing carbon dioxide to create their food and releasing oxygen as waste is a lie.

Comment: sure plants then take that food and combine it with oxygen to make ATP. the net change in oxygen in the atmosphere is zero. the only carbon that is sequestered is the carbon in the plant tissue which is released as soon as they are eaten or decompose.  seagrass is going to sequester less carbon than coral. you are creating the opposite of the intended effect.

Comment: @JohnWDailey: Because plants absorb carbon while they live, but when they die and rot, or are eaten, most of it returns to the atmosphere.  So to have a net reduction in atmospheric CO2, you'd have to 1) Increase the total living biomass; 2) Sequester some of the organic material as e.g. soil humus; or 3) Bury the organic material somehow.

Comment: Coral on the other hand creates a solid sequestration of carbon that does not decompose and gets buried as new coral grows. It sequesters a lot of carbon.Plants only sequester a very tiny amount of transient carbon and do not emit any net oxygen.

Comment: @John  You know, you talk about one thing but not the other.  Still, where else does Earth get its oxygen?  Lava eruptions?

Comment: @JohnWDailey  The Earth's oxygen built up over millions of years as organic carbon from (first of all) dead sea creatures/plankton then later dead coal forest trees was buried in sediments and turned into rocks so it couldn't decay. (Meanwhile reef builders were removing CO2). The volume of oxygen in the atmosphere is HUGE. Modern plants add a tiny bit to that volume every year. Animals breathing and things rotting remove a tiny bit each year. An analogy is a bath filled up to the brim with water. A dripping tap is the annual O2 in, a trickle down the overflow is the annual O2 out.

Comment: @John Photosynthesizerds, including plants, absolutely do produce net oxygen. They produced [all the free oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event) that ever was and ever will be on earth. I can prove to you that plants release more oxygen than they use through respiration: you are currently breathing oxygen.

Comment: @ kingledion Cyanobacteria produce net oxygen. They are also the ones that produced the oxygen you breath, and oxygenated the early earth. Plants do not. Cyanobacteria also do not need oxygen to survive unlike plants, for cyanobacteria it is a waste product.

Comment: The chloroplasts plants use to photosynthesis originated as relatives to cyanobacteria. Plants had not even evolved when the atmosphere was oxygenated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event

Comment: @John From a UC-Santa Barbara [learning site](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=2860), _Fortunately for all of us oxygen breathers, plants produce approximately ten times more oxygen during the day that what they consume at night._ Plants are net oxygen produces, just as cyanobactria and other photosynthesizers are.

Comment: Which as I pointed out is rebalanced as soon as something eats them. and the real number for plants is closer to 60% not 1000% So I can only assume they are including something besides plants. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2486.2001.00448.x/abstract;jsessionid=DE4DC5701DF0EB50F446C2906BD38413.f03t02

Comment: It also zero's out across forest or field of seagrass unless it is expanding, becasue there is little to carbon sequestration. I suspect UCsanta-barbra is incorrectly including algae and cyanobacteria as plants, it's the only way they could be getting the absurd number since algae produce ~75% of the oxygen on the planet.

Comment: I see part of the problem, you think I mean net by if you stick a single plant in a jar by itself there will be no increase in oxygen. I said net for forest ,for the ecosystem they are part of. If you put an entire forest in jar including the animals that live there is little to no change in oxygen or carbon. you have to sequester the carbon for that to happen and most plant based ecosystems don't do a lot of that. bogs (and deep sea algae) sequester becasue when they die they fall into anaerobic environments and do not rot much and what little they do is done without oxygen.

Answer (score -2):

Many filter feeders preferentially concentrate some nasty chemicals; however transplanting species should be approached with considerable caution.  And some mussel species, accidentally transported, have become serious pests, for example the Zebra Mussel: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_mussel

Neither are all species of seaweed nice to have around, either.  Which species you foster *matters*.  Please don't use this one: 
https://www.invasivespeciesinfo.gov/aquatics/caulerpa.shtml

On the other hand, we can add rocks or similar to sandy or muddy shallows, to give sessile sea creatures anchor points against the current.  Just any old junk doesn't work, however.  Attempts to use old tires to foster artificial reefs haven't worked very well.  Concrete and old ships seem to do much better for increasing the local biota.

Comment: _"Despite claims that as many as half of fish species have disappeared from areas where Caulerpa grows, scientific studies have shown that fish diversity and biomass are equal or greater in Caulerpa meadows than in seagrass beds, that Caulerpa had no effect on composition or richness of fish species, and that species richness and epiphytic plant diversity is greater in Caulerpa than in pure sea grass. Thus, [...] the species appears to have many beneficial ecological effects on aquatic communities in the Mediterranean Sea."_ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caulerpa_taxifolia))

Comment: Who said anything about "transplanting"?  Also, it's seaGRASS, not seaWEED.